# Winsock C++ Multithreaded Server not receiving Client response

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock, recv

I am trying to create a multithreaded server that will create a new thread for every socket connected. I have it so everytime there is a connection, a new thread is created and a message is sent from the server to the client but I cannot get a response from the client to the server to send without getting the `10038 error`. I would like to make the thread always listening and waiting for a response until it gets one and then continuing. Is this possible to do while still accepting new connections?

Below is the relevant portion of my code (I removed a lot of the socket set up steps).

Server Code:

```
DWORD WINAPI myThread(LPVOID lpParameter){

TCHAR recvBuffer[] = { 0 };
ZeroMemory(recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer));
int recvBufferLen = 4096;
int iSendResult;
int iResult;
SOCKET ClientSocket1 = (SOCKET)lpParameter;

iResult = recv(ClientSocket1, (char*)recvBuffer, recvBufferLen, 0);
while (iResult > 0){
    wprintf(L"Bytes received Port %d -> %s\n", iResult, recvBuffer);
}
wprintf(L"Not received\n");
return 0;
}

// Listen for connections
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    while (1){
        ClientSocket1 = INVALID_SOCKET;
        // Accept a Connection
        while (ClientSocket1 == INVALID_SOCKET){
            ClientSocket1 = accept(ListenSocket1, NULL, NULL);
        }
        wprintf(L"Client Connected. \n");
        DWORD myThreadID;
        HANDLE handle = CreateThread(0, 0, myThread, (LPVOID)ClientSocket1, 0, &myThreadID);
        Sleep(10000);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Client Code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

TCHAR recvBuffer[] = { 0 };
int recvBufferLen = 10000;
wchar_t sendBuf[] = { 0 };
int iSendResult;
// Receive Menu

iResult = recv(ConnectSocket1, (char*)recvBuffer, 512, 0);
if (iResult > 0){
    wprintf(L"%s", recvBuffer);


    // Send choice
    do{
        wprintf(L"Please input a choice:\n");
        fgetws(sendBuf, 10, stdin);
    } while (!(_wtoi(sendBuf) >= 1 && _wtoi(sendBuf) <= 6));

    iSendResult = send(ConnectSocket1, (char*)sendBuf, 4096, 0);
    if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
        wprintf(L"Send Failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket1);
        WSACleanup();
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }
    wprintf(L"Message Sent.\n");

}
}
```

Comment: **UPDATE** - I fixed it. For anyone wondering, the sleep was messing it all up

Comment: the `sleep` is not the reason for your problems. There are other, more important, problems in your code. Such as buffer overflows. Error code 10038 is `WSAENOTSOCK`. Your are not allocating your buffers correctly, so you are likely overwriting the call stack, corrupting your `SOCKET` variables. No `sleep` (or lack of) would fix that. You are not managing memory correctly, THAT is what you need to fix.